# Swift Image Name Compare

Tags: swift, image

I am using the below code to work out if the image name in box1Image is equal to "sallywin.png".

Id doesnt seem to work.

How would I go about coding this?

Any help much appreciated

```html
if (box1Image.image?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "smswin.png")))! {
            
            self.box1Image.image = UIImage(named:"sallywin.png")
        }
```

Comment: I think you should use the `tag` property of your imageView to get it state. Juste change it when you change the image inside it

Comment: Is box1Image a UIButton?

Comment: Please don't include the answer in your question. If an answer solved your issue, mark the answer as accepted; you can also post your own answer if you resolved your problem yourself. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly compare two images are same. You can get the images as NSDATA and then you can compare two NSDATA values are equal.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare 2 images using NSData.

```
let imageName1 : UIImage =  UIImage(named: "Selected_1.png")!
let imageName2 : UIImage =  UIImage(named: "UnSelected.png")!
let imageView = UIImageView(image: imageName1)

    if imageCompare(imageView.image!, isEqualTo: imageName2)
    {
        print("TRUE")
    }
    else
    {
        print("FALSE")
    }

func imageCompare(image1: UIImage, isEqualTo image2: UIImage) -> Bool {
    let data1: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1)!
    let data2: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2)!
    return data1.isEqual(data2)
}
```