# IOS/Swift: check for button image to toggle button image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am just learning Swift and am trying to toggle a button based on a user action between two images. It would be nice to just check the name of the images showing and toggle to the other one.

I am able to get the image from the button but not necessarily it's name.  My question is how to compare it to the image name in Swift.

```
func toggleImage(){
    var img = self.sendButton.image(for: .normal)//NO ERROR
    if img.isEqual(image-one) {
        //ERROR HERE
        //switch to image-two
    } else {
        //switch to image-one
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891315/swift-image-name-compare

Comment: You chose very hard way of achieving what you want. Consider using different images for different states of `UIButton`, like `selected` and normal. This way, when tapped you can switch selected property of the button to true or false, and image will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using  ===

   `private let image-one = UIImage(named: "name1")
    private let image-two = UIImage(named: "name2")
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        sendButton.setImage(image-one, for: .normal)
    }

    func toggle image() {
      if self.sendButton.currentImage === image-one {
            .....
      } 
    }`
2. Using flags (less elegant, but much safer):

   `enum WhichImage {
       case image-one, image-two
     }
     private var whichImage: WhichImage = .image-one`

Instead of checking images you check `whichImage` and update it when image is changed.

Comment: Should this work if private let image-one = ... is inside the function?

Comment: user6631314. It should.  Who cares matter where the assignment is done?!

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way. Treat the button like a checkbox. The unchecked state is image 1, the checked state is image 2.

To setup a `UIButton` to work like a checkbox, use the `isSelected` property.

```
sendButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "image1"), for: .normal)
sendButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "image2"), for: .selected)

// You may also need to set the image for the highlighted selected state.
sendButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "image2"), for: [.selected, .highlighted])
```

Now that the button knows about both images, you can switch between the to using the `isSelected` property.

```
func toggleImage() {
    sendButton.isSelected = !sendButton.isSelected
}
```

Comment: This is a nice approach, however, I may need to use isselected at some point as well. There are actually three states. img, img1-selected and img2

Answer (score 2):

Set Images in Interface approach the just change state of button in code.

[image]
[image]

Here is the code to change the state

```
 @IBAction func fastButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    fastButton.isSelected = !fastButton.isSelected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get image name and compare it like below

```
  if self.sendButton.currentImage == UIImage(named: "image-one") {
           //switch to image-two
            }else {
    //switch to image-one
        }
```

Comment: That's will cause reloading "image-one" all the time, which is terribly inefficient.

Comment: @cyanide you can make a variable that can load on start or use lazy variable to load once it start using. We can optimize it according to requirements.

Comment: So you need to change the code sample accordingly, otherwise it is misleading.